# bash cat: invalid option -- 'r'

Tags: cat, xargs

Searched every for the invalid option `-r` for the `cat` command on our RedHat enterprise 7.7 Maipo (???) server, but no luck.

Attempting to read in a list of file names with full path, open the file listed in `filelist.log`, and append the *contents* of that file into one large file.

As an example, if `filelist.log` has a list of five file names and their full paths:

```
1st file in the list consists of 10 lines.                                                              
2nd file in list is 4 lines.                                 
3rd file in list is 7 lines                                 
4th file in list is 6 lines.                                        
5th file in list is 3 lines.
```

... then the file created would have 30 lines.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line                                   
do echo "$line"  #works fine, echos line-by-line of file name and path to stdout.

cat "$line" >>sourcecode.txt #append CONTENTS of file, (throws invalid option 'r')                               
done < filelist.log
```

Maybe this is the wrong approach.

Other attempts that threw the same invalid option `-r` error:

```
cat $(grep -v '^#' filelist.log) >sourcecode.txt                      
sed '/^$/d;/^#/d;s/^/cat "/;s/$/";/' filelist.log | sh  > sourcecode.txt    
xargs < filelist.log cat >>sourcecode.txt
```

Have used xargs in past to read in a list of five levels of folder names, and then create a set of the same folder names on another server, but empty, so it seems that would work here also.

Comment: Might one of your files just be called `-r` or something like `file -red` or alike? `read` separates on whitespaces and newlines. Use an approach which delimits file names with the zero-byte.

Comment: Try with `cat -- "$line"`

Comment: Could you please include real code and a real filelist.log to work with?  It is difficult to advise otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

During the loop, `cat` is encountering a "$line" that starts with `-r`, then it thinks is an option to the command:

```
cat -rfoo
```

so it throws the error

```
cat: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

You can bypass it by telling the command to don't accept more options with `--`

```
cat -- "$line"
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Works now.                            I can  build a code base out of program files saved all over the network, in hundreds of different directories  then zip it up.                                                     SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO awesome

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `IFS=`, you don't need that in this case.

```bash
while read -r line; do cat -- "$line" ; done < filelist >> outputfile
```

Will do the trick.